# I can't click on the link that has `<a>` tag and no href attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, userscripts

I am making a bot that locates a page and automatically finds an "href" like so `<a class="batteekh"></a>` what I want is just to click this hyperlink in any way I can.

After selecting my hyperlink `$(".batteekh").attr("style","background-color:red")` I changed the background-color to red and it works but what is happening is that I can't click on that link that has no `href` attribute.

I've searched a lot and tried several statements but none works:

- `$(".batteekh").trigger("click");`
- `$(".batteekh").click()`
- `$(".batteekh").get(0).click()`

Thanks in advance!

**I am trying to auto vote up a question in stackoverlow**

**EDIT:**

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Stackoverflow Voter
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @require      http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

$(".vote-up-off").attr("style","background-color:red")[0].click();
```

**NOTE : I am using this for learning purpose only**

Comment: `$(".batteekh")[0].click()` should work - assuming it's the first element in the DOM with that class

Comment: @MagnusIngwersen "I can't click on that link that *has no href attribute*."

Comment: the .click() is used by jQuery to assign an onclick function like: `.click(function(){})`

Comment: It wouldn't.  They are mistaken.  `.click()` (with no arguments) triggers any click event:  https://api.jquery.com/click/  it's the same as `.trigger( "click" )`

Comment: @MagnusIngwersen **no** what @BrankVictoria is completely wrong. Calling `click` without arguments triggers the event handlers. You need to pass an argument to bind a handler.

Comment: I see. I will pull my comments of this to avoid anyone else getting confused! Thanks for correcting

Comment: @YoussofHammoud do you want to trigger inline `onclick="..."` handlers ?

Comment: If there are many elements, you should do `$(".batteekh").each(function(){this.click();})`. This will trigger the click handler of each element.

Comment: there is no no `onclick` attribute.No i don't want to trigger onclick="";

Comment: @YoussofHammoud So what would you like to happen when you click on a `a` tag with not `href` attribute ?

Comment: You seem like a man with bad intentions, that's why you cannot come right... I don't think people here can help you with Hacking techniques...

Comment: @Morgs Actually I intended to say automatically in the question but I am using it in another way I am using keycode that calls this function when it's fired I hope I explained well, and no It is not for hacking I am just making a shortcut key that votes up whenever I need.Thanks.

Comment: Ok see my suggestion below...

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli I edited my question.I appreciate your help but I think that the vote up button has an <kbd>event</kbd> when I opened the link in firefox Do you think an event can accessed or clicked??

Comment: @YoussofHammoud are you sure `$(".batteekh")[0].click()` does not work ? Of course it will not work on your own question, since you are not allowed to upvote your own questions.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli It worked but after 2 mins later it doesn't is there something wrong with the tampermonkey or it is just my luck.

Answer (score 3):

I think `$(".batteekh")[0].click()` should handle a click in your situation.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, generally, an href tag defines where the browser should take you once clicked, so if there isn't one then nothing will happen. However, most people will use `<a>...</a>` with a click event which seems like what you're attempting. If you trigger `$(".batteekh").click()` and nothing happens, it simply, simply mean that there's no click event attached to your button or that a click event attached to your button does, nothing.

So, start off by finding out if you've first off attached a click event to your button? e.g. Below is how I can define a click event for your button:

```
$(".batteekh")
.unbind("click")
.bind("click", function ()
{
   alert('Got here first!!');
});
```

In your firebug (Firefox) you can for instance put `$(".batteekh")` and press enter, if you investigate the object you'll be able to see what events are attached to that button...

Comment: thanks for your explanation but when I attached your code to mine it didn't work.Can you explain why I can't click `<a></a>` tag using JQuery code.Or it works but I am failing in doing it.

Comment: can you explain futrther to your answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example:
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thezeeshantariq/uLc8r6m1/2/)

```
<a class="batteekh" style="cursor: pointer;">Link 1</a>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
    $('.batteekh').click(function(){
    alert("You clicked me?");
});
```

In case you have multiple links:

```
$('.batteekh').click(function(){
  $(this).click(function(){
    alert("You clicked me?");
  });
});
```